# Removing symbols from laptop keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I would like to have an all-black keyboard on my laptop. I want the built-in keyboard to look like this:

[image]

What is the best approach?

- Try to remove the symbols?
- Paint with black paint?

Has anyone done this? How?

The laptop is a compaq nc 6000.

Comment: Everybody, thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine grit sandpaper or paint both work well.

Comment: What kind of paint should I buy?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of re-selling in the future i reccomend, permanent marker or paint

so in the future can be removed to see the keys

Comment: I agree for re-selling you shouldn't do something too final.  You could always buy a spare keyboard on ebay, and spray paint it flat black/sandpaper that way if you do sell it you still have an original.

Comment: permanent marker, in my experience, does not work; it rubs off. i have tried Sharpies and a store brand pen from an art store, and both last only for about a week, at best. (caveat: i use my keyboard A LOT).

Answer (score 2):

You can [buy Typing and Keyboard Blank Key-top Stickers (Black)](http://hooleon.com/miva/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=OV-0645&Category_Code=FS-TM&Product_Count=1)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to folks who make custom key caps, and just specify black blanks (should be cheap!)

These guys, came up on a Google search

[The Key Connection](http://www.customkeys.com/customprinting.html?s=gaw&kw=keycaps&gclid=CMeU9pn9jJ0CFdFL5QodhDRA1A),

[Syntronics](http://www.synctronics.com/)